# Java equivalent to c# list declaration

Tags: java, c#, object, variables

i whould like to know if there is an equivalent in java to this:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>(){
    new Person{
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe"
    },
    new Person{
        FirstName = "Someone",
        LastName = "Special"
    }
};
```

Assuming, of course... there is a class called Person with FirstName and LastName fields with {get;set;}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Java 9 you can write

```
// immutable list
List<Person> People = List.of(
                          new Person("John", "Doe"),
                          new Person("Someone", "Special"));
```

From Java 5.0 you could write

```
// cannot add or remove from this list but you can replace an element.
List<Person> People = Arrays.asList(
                          new Person("John", "Doe"),
                          new Person("Someone", "Special"));
```

From Java 1.4 you can write

```
// mutable list
List<Person> People = new ArrayList<Person>() {{
                          add(new Person("John", "Doe"));
                          add(new Person("Someone", "Special"));
                      }};
```

Comment: Note that `List.of` returns an immutable list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! it worked like a charm! :)